# CPU time in iteration process

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, finite-element-method, iteration, timing

Let $Tx=\frac{x}{2}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ and set an iterative sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ by the method $x_{n+1}=Tx_{n}$. Now if $x_{0}=0.8$, then I get a convergent sequence towards the unique fixed point of $T$ as follows. But I need the CPU time in this case. How I set the CPU time or where I can check the CPU time for method.

```
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2);
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]];
NumberForm[{Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}]}, 9]
{{0.9, 0.45, 0.225, 0.1125, 0.05625, 0.028125, 0.0140625, 0.00703125}}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How I set the CPU time or where I can check the CPU time for method

One way is to use `TimeUsed[]` and at the end subtract the times. Something like this

```
t0 = TimeUsed[];
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2);
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]];
Quiet@NumberForm[{Table[x[i], {i, 0, 100000}]}, 9];
Print["time used in CPU seconds is ", TimeUsed[] - t0]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

If you want clock time used (not CPU time), then you can use `AbsoluteTiming` but note this measures time elapsed, not CPU time. This are not the same. So it depends on what you want.

Comment: Thanks dear @Nasser thanks for you helpful answer. However with every click, the value changes for CPU time. For example,  0.25, 0.281 etc in my CPU

Comment: @JunaidAhmad you need to reset `t0`  (initial time) each time where you want to measure the CPU time used.